# Google Play Store Billing problem in case of 'Two Android Apps in One Firebase Container'

Tags: android, firebase, google-play-console, android-billing

I'm managing two apps in one Firebase. For monthly payment, I registered each app separately in the Google Play Console and made a monthly payment product for each app, and called each product using the API from each client app. The first app makes regular payments well, but when the second app calls the API, there is an error saying "the list of subscription products is 0". What are the potential problems?

I just have look through the codes but there seems no problem. I guess the reason could be Googles policies or a setting problem for the case of 'Two Android Apps in One Firebase Container'. Here, I need an advice.